# CMake seemingly incorrect behavior of IN_LIST keyword

Tags: macos, cmake, osx-yosemite

I am trying to use the new logic in CMake 3.3 that checks if a value is in a list

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0057 NEW)

set(l A B C)
foreach( e ${l} ) 
  if( ${e} IN_LIST "${l}" )
    message( "element ${e} found in ${l}" )
  else()
    message( "element ${e} NOT found in ${l}" )
  endif()
endforeach()
```

Running this with CMake 3.4.3 on OSX Yosemite gives an unexpected result:

```
$ cmake -P cmakeBug.cmake
element A NOT found in A;B;C
element B NOT found in A;B;C
element C NOT found in A;B;C
```

Am I missing something trivial or is there a bug in CMake?

Answer (score 17):

Try `IF ( ${e} IN_LIST l )`. [According to the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/if.html) the second argument is a list variable, not a list.

Comment: Something else to add... Ensure `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION)` is 3.3 or greater. I hit some problems because the old CMake script was set to 3.0 and used that version even though I had 3.16 installed.